# Merge Office 2013 Calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have users with office 365 calendars and some local. How can I merge them all into one calendar account that can be easily shared?

I've tried doing a copy and drag and drop with no luck.

Comment: Try "Import/Export"  - if that is available (File menu?).

Comment: With Inport/Export can I import a bunch of calendars together though?

Comment: Sorry, can't tell - never tried this.